# DSolve expression not evaluating

Tags: differential-equations

I entered the following into *Mathematica*:

```
p[x_] := 4 x
q[x_] := 4 Sqrt[x] - 3
f[x_] := E^-Sqrt[x]
DSolve[y''[x] + p[x] y'[x] + q[x] y[x] == f[x], y[x], x]
```

> ```
>  DSolve[
>     (-3 + 4 Sqrt[x]) y[x] + 4 x Derivative[1][y][x] + 
>       (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == E^-Sqrt[x],
>     y[x], x]
> ```

Why is Mathematica refusing to evaluate my DSolve expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If DSolve doesn't evaluate and you have used correct syntax, that means DSolve is not aware of a symbolic solution to your differential equation.

You may want to find a numeric solution using NDSolve or using some kind of approximation to simplify the problem down.